# Visual Studio Versioning

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, versioning

We have a solution with multiple projects that all spit out exe files. We have a shared VersionAssemblyInfo.cs that has the following...

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.5.*")]
```

This works fine and all exe's are versioned with the correct major, minor and build number. However the Revision is always different. Now i understand why this is, but is there a way to get the final revision to always be the same if the solution is built in one go? I would still like to take advantage of the automatic incrementation. So i don't really want to have to hardcode it and change it all the time.

Comment: By shared do you mean the item is added as a linked-item in each project?

Comment: the revision is something like "the second since midnight" so I guess that your projects are not compiled at the same time. Theres no out of the box way to auto increment the version number.

Comment: @Lloyd - Thats right they are linked

Comment: @TomSchardt - Yeah thought that may be the case. Might have to do something nasty to bodge it

Comment: @MrBeanzy yes, maybe something in build events...

Comment: Thanks Tom, i'll knock something together and post the outcome.

Comment: Can you show the build log here?

Comment: Which build agent uses? Hosted or private agent? The source or output always be cleaned if you are using Hosted agent, so the version will be always different.

Answer (score -1):

To keep the final revision stay the same, you just need to set clean build as **`false`** in Get sources build step and queue the build with [**private agent**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows).

[image]

Then the revision always with the same value for different times of build.

Comment: @MrBeanzy To keep the revision same, you should also queue the build on your private agent. Please have a try on private agent.

Comment: Yes also on a private agent

Comment: But if you build on private agent and set Clean as false at the same time, the revision will be the same value even you build for many times. Can you add the build logs which you meant the revision are different?